# how to remove the accent in fonts

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

Hi I have used a font but the letter with the accent shows in bold like this Yasemin enar **ğ** uloo. I want it to show without the letter with the accent getting affected in bold.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use the letter?

Comment: It's a name so I need to use very single letter. But for some reason because the g has an accent on it (^) it is showing it in bold for some reason...

Comment: Can you show some code and tell what font you are using?

Answer (score 1):

if you check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp you'll see that there are only 3 possible text-transformations: Uppercase, Lowercase and Capitalize. Besides, `g` and `ğ` are different characters, as are `e` and `é`. You cannot simply interchange it with CSS, it needs to be done with a programming language like PHP or Javascript.